# matplotlib bar plot adjust bar direction

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axes

I want to start the bars from the bottom. How can I change the starting point from zero to e.g. -2 ?

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


N=1000
sample=np.random.random_integers(1,10,N)
hist,bins=np.histogram(sample)

plt.bar(bins[:-1],np.log10(1.*hist/N),np.diff(bins))

plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, removed the commentary because I realized of another thing. I think you'll find that it did change, but just slightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

`plt.bar(bins[:-1],abs(np.log10(1.*hist/N)),np.diff(bins))`

Comment: I want to keep the y-axis labels as they are, because it's the logarithm

Comment: Hardythe1 is on the right track. Now just add bottom=-2 within the plt.bar()

Comment: thx! this worked now: `plt.bar(bins[:-1],2-abs(np.log10(1.*hist/N)),np.diff(bins),bottom=-2)`